# content query web part with multi value lookup column

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, content-query-web-part, multiple-values

I am trying to work out how I can query a content type with a multi value lookup field using the content query web part.

I know that natively this is not possible with ootb sharepoint 2010 however I have seen various blog posts about workarounds to this limitation.

eg.

- [Displaying Multi-Select Column Values in CrossList DVWPs](http://sympmarc.com/2011/09/20/displaying-multi-select-column-values-in-crosslist-dvwps/)

however I have not been able to get this to work on a content query web part and we only have sharepoint foundation so no data view webpart. :-(

Any ideas suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, you have to add the ID field of the lookup field to the list (Edit the listcolumn and check ID in the extra fields section).
Than you can filter based on that field "fieldname:Id"